# Pick and choose what categories are added to a menu in a categorylist

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu

I am trying to create a menu in Joomla and want to pick and choose what categories are added in my categorylist menu. Now I can pick a parent category and it will list all sub categories, but what if I want only a few? Or what if I want to add a category that is under a different parent category to this menu? How can I do that?

I am using Joomla 3.9.23

Comment: Please include your findings while researching and attempting to self-solve so that members of this community don't feel as if they are doing free development work for you.

Comment: @mickmackusa I don't want free development work. Maybe someone knows how to do this in the Joomla admin. I cannot find it.

Comment: Your question is currently a "requirements dump" that shows no proof of research/effort.  According to my own set of Stack Exchange principles, I cannot upvote requirements dumps.  If you improve your question, then it may be more attractive to volunteers and may qualify for upvotes.